# Unit testing memory leaks using xUnit

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, memory-leaks

I recently read [this article](https://michaelscodingspot.com/find-fix-and-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c-net-8-best-practices/) and it was all about finding, fixing and avoiding memory leaks. I had a feeling that my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app was leaking because it kept increasing the memory usage for the first few minutes but after I kept it opened for like 5 minutes, it sticked to 350 MB in the *Diagnostic Tools* in Visual Studio 2019. Everything is probably okay because I usually don't forget to dispose stuff (by *using* block) but I wanted to make sure because my web app is listening to web sockets event for lifetime unless a CancellationToken is requested by the user.

[image]

In that article, I saw that it's possible to test an object for memory leak.

```
[Test]
void MemoryLeakTest()
{
  var weakRef = new WeakReference(leakyObject)
  // Ryn an operation with leakyObject
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();
  Assert.IsFalse(weakRef.IsAlive);
}
```

Can the following code be tested for memory leaks in unit testing using xUnit? More specifically, `timer` and `_subscription`.

```
using Binance.Entity;
using Binance.Extensions;
using Binance.Helpers;
using Binance.Interfaces;
using Binance.Models.Redis;
using Binance.Net;
using Binance.Net.Interfaces;
using Binance.Net.Objects;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Authentication;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Sockets;
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Binance.Services
{
    public interface IBotService
    {
        void RunStart(Bot bot);
        Task StopAsync();
    }

    public class BotService : IBotService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IBinanceClient _client;
        private readonly IBinanceSocketClient _socketClient;
        private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;

        public BotService(
            ILogger<BotService> logger,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IBinanceClient client,
            IBinanceSocketClient socketClient,
            INotificationService notificationService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _client = client;
            _socketClient = socketClient;
            _notificationService = notificationService;
        }

        private void ApplyCredentialsOnClient()
        {
            BinanceClient.SetDefaultOptions(new BinanceClientOptions()
            {
                ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(_configuration.GetValue<string>("BinanceConfig:ApiKey"), _configuration.GetValue<string>("BinanceConfig:SecretKey")),
                AutoTimestamp = true,
                AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
            });

            BinanceSocketClient.SetDefaultOptions(new BinanceSocketClientOptions()
            {
                ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(_configuration.GetValue<string>("BinanceConfig:ApiKey"), _configuration.GetValue<string>("BinanceConfig:SecretKey")),
                AutoReconnect = true,
                ReconnectInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
            });
        }

        private UpdateSubscription _subscription;

        public void RunStart(Bot bot)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Start(bot));
        }

        public void Start(Bot bot)
        {
            ApplyCredentialsOnClient();

            bool locked = false;
            Timer timer = null; 

            BinanceKline lastKnownKline = null;
            _subscription = _socketClient.SubscribeToKlineUpdates(bot.CryptoPair.Symbol, bot.TimeInterval.Interval, async data =>
            {
                if (data.Data.Final)
                {
                    lastKnownKline = data.Data.ToKline();

                    // Static logic

                    // Clean up
                    if (locked)
                    {
                        locked = false;
                        timer?.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                // This block won't be executed before the static block is executed first
                else if (lastKnownKline != null && lastKnownKline.Close != data.Data.Close)
                {
                    lastKnownKline = data.Data.ToKline();

                    if (!locked)
                    {
                        locked = true;

                        timer = new Timer(async state =>
                        {
                            // Real time logic

                            bool condition = true;
                            if (condition)
                            {
                                timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
                            }
                        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(scheduledTime));
                    }
                }
            }).Data;
        }

        public async Task StopAsync()
        {
            await _socketClient.Unsubscribe(_subscription);
        }

        private bool _disposed = false;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                _client.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disposing is just about being responsible with memory usage. It technically doesn't matter, as the GC will collect it all eventually. That's not a "memory leak".

Comment: @ChrisPratt, that's right.

Comment: I still want to unit test that in order to be certain.